# User does not have any of the necessary access rights Error

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, laratrust

I used Lara-trust to set roles and permissions:
This is DatabaseSeeder.php file  in database directory:

```
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call([
            LaratrustSeeder::class,
            UsersTableSeeder::class,
        ]);
```

And My UsersTable seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    //

    $user = App\User::create([
        'name'=>'super_admin',
        'email'=>'super_admin@app.com',
        'password'=>bcrypt('123456'),
        'name'=>'super_admin'
    ]);

    $user->attachRole('super_admin');
} //end of run
```

Now I can NOT browse my Dashboard Panel even after log in successfully, I just get ***403
User does not have any of the necessary access rights.***
[Log in done but can Not browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLzOw.jpg)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have the `super_admin` role set in the DB since according to LaraTrust docs, there is a default role `superadministrator` instead. So then you must create one, and assign permissions.

Source:
https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/5.2/configuration/seeder.html

Comment: thanks niklaz ,but  I checked it  and found super_admin role in my DB, still have the error

Comment: @shaza, did you check then your permissions for accessing the dashboard, and see if these permissions are assigned to the `super_admin` role?

Comment: This is  the laratrust_seeder.php  in config:                  return [
    'role_structure' => [
        'super_admin' => [
            'users' => 'c,r,u,d',
            'categories' => 'c,r,u,d'

        ],

Comment: @shaza, and what about the method or controller, or middleware that checks the correct permission that user has to access the dashboard?

Comment: this id my middleware      Route::prefix('dashboard')
->name('dashboard.')
->middleware(['auth','role:super_admin|admin'])
->group(function(){

Comment: @shaza, did you try to run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: I tried now cache and config clear, did NOT work, I tried also to log out and log in again, I logged in , but when type /dashboard in url, it gives again User does not have any of the necessary access rights.

Comment: @shaza, are you sure the role is `super_admin` not `super-admin`?

Comment: yes, I changed to underscore in laratrustSeeder.php to be super_admin like this:      $permissions[] = \App\Permission::firstOrCreate([
                        'name' => $permissionValue . '_' . $module,

Comment: I solved it by changing route to be Super_admin capital S:         ->middleware(['auth','role:Super_admin|admin']) 
Thanks a lot for help